# Rails 4 Nested_form remove link after 5 questions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am using a nested form gem in which i have two fields, the view is given as

```
<%= f.fields_for :round_questions do |question| %>
                          <%= question.label :question %>
                          <%= question.text_field :question %>
                              Rate the Answer</br></br>
                           <div class="star-questions" ></div>
                          <%= question.text_field :answer_rating, :class=> 'star-answer', :disabled=>true %>
                          <%= question.link_to_remove "Remove this Question" %>
                      <% end %>
                      <%= f.link_to_add "Add a Question", :round_questions,
                                        :class=> 'btn waves-effect waves-light btn-medium custom_btn_gray' %>
```

and in the controller i have

```
@interview_round = InterviewRound.where(id: params[:id]).first
    5.times {@interview_round.round_questions.build}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
```

now when the form loads there will be 5 questions present, I want to give the remove link only when someone adds a question but this link gives remove link to all questions, 
Please tell me how can I solve this ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you provide a screen-shot of the current and what you are expecting?

Comment: see actually when the page loads there will be 5 questions field because i have given  "5.times {@interview_round.round_questions.build}"
 so now i want that remove link only after the 5th question that is being produced after clicking add a question button

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it like this

```
<%= question.link_to_remove "Remove this Question" if question.object.persisted? %>
```

Comment: the console is giving error ( undefined method `persisted?' for #<NestedForm::Builder:0xb3f165f4>)

Comment: link is not showing for either of the questions and no console errors either

Comment: @nishantvarshney Yes the link wont appear unless you add a question. Is that what you wanted right.

Comment: link is not appearing even if i add question

Comment: @nishantvarshney Can you please provide a screen-shot of the behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80662/discussion-between-nishant-varshney-and-pavan).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition while showing remove link as follow:

```
<%= question.link_to_remove "Remove this Question" unless question.object.new_record? %>
```

Comment: the console is giving error ( undefined method `new_record?' for #<NestedForm::Builder:0xb3057784>)

Comment: Use `question.object.new_record?` instead.

Comment: @MichaelChaney - not working , it is showing the remove link on all the fields